# WPF DataGrid: How To Keep Selected Rows Highlighted?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have multiple DataGrid controls on the same window in my WPF project.  When I click a row in a grid it highlights.  When I click a row in another grid that row highlights and the row in the first grid becomes very faintly highlighted.  How can I design this window so that each grid can display a selected row as highlighted all at the same time?  My project is built in .NET 4.0 so the InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey doesn't seem to work.  I'm using the code below, and it basically works except when I click a different grid the previous grid changes the row text color to black instead of white.  I tried setting ControlTextBrushKey to White, but that made every row in the grid turn white meaning the unselected rows because invisible because the background is also white.  Is there a more elegant way to do this by creating a user control or inheriting from the DataGrid class because I will need to insert this code many times in the project.

```html
                <DataGrid Name="dgStores" >
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static Colors.DodgerBlue}"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static Colors.DodgerBlue}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the IsSelected colors for DataGridCell using Style.Triggers.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrush}"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: That didn't work.  It behaves basically like a normal grid.  When I click a row it's highlighted in blue.  When I click a row in a second grid the highlighted row in the first grid becomes very faintly highlighted.

Comment: Ok I'll take another look